# HTML выбор с помощью тега select

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

есть задача:

> ...сделать выбор названия картинки с помощью тега "select"

Вот часть кода, в котором нужно сделать изменение:

```
<select name = "picture">
            <option>winter.jpg</option>
            <option>spring.jpg</option>
            <option>fall.jpg</option>
            <option>summer.jpg</option>
        </select>
        <img src = "${picture}" name = "myimage">
```

я уже пробовал передать через $

> <img src = "${picture}" name = "myimage"

но не работает... не выбирает картинку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#picture-name').change(function() {
    console.log($(this).find("option:selected").text());
    $('#picture').attr('src', $(this).find("option:selected").text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="picture" id="picture-name">
  <option>winter.jpg</option>
  <option>spring.jpg</option>
  <option>fall.jpg</option>
  <option>summer.jpg</option>
</select>
<img src="${picture}" name="myimage" id="picture">
```

```js
let select = document.querySelector('#picture-name');

select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.value); 
  document.querySelector('#picture').setAttribute('src', event.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="picture" id="picture-name">
  <option>winter.jpg</option>
  <option>spring.jpg</option>
  <option>fall.jpg</option>
  <option>summer.jpg</option>
</select>
<img src="${picture}" name="myimage" id="picture">
```

Comment: А проще возможно?) просто это для колледжа, могут придераться, если нет, отправлю тогда так) а так то работает все

Comment: А что есть '"проще" в твоём понимании?

Comment: Типа без jquery и прочих библиотек. Я в JS не очень просто, я больше на плюсах пишу. По этому спрашиваю)

Comment: Добавил без jquery

Comment: Спасибо! Огромное!